# jQuery $.get not firing in IE7 or 8 - XML RSS

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, rss

I am using $.get() to obtain an RSS feed. This works in FF and chrome but is not firing at all in IE7 or IE8. I assume this is the headers or encoding.

The jQuery function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        $.get('/resources/xml/feed.rss', 'xml' , function(data) {
            // This never fires in IE7 or IE8 <----------------------
            alert('GET INITIATED!');

            $('.news-announcements').html('');
            var i = 0;

            $(data).find('item').each(function() {
                if (i < 5) {
                    var $item = $(this);
                    var title = $item.find('title').text();
                    var link = $item.find('link').text();
                    var date = $item.find('pubDate').text();

                    var html = '<blockquote><div class="ItemTitle"><a target="_blank" href="' + link + '">' + title + '</a></div><div class="ItemDate">'+ date +'</div></blockquote>';
                    i++;

                    $('.news-announcements').append(html);
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

The xml is encoded as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

Comment: *"not firing at all"* are you sure? add an error callback, i bet it's being called with the error text "parseerror"

Comment: I added $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert(error);
    }
   });

........... I am seeing Error: Invalid XML

Comment: well there you go. IE thinks your xml is invalid.

Comment: ....special characters. Specifically, the hyphen. Thanks a bunch.. what a giant waste of two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyphens must be escaped using the ascii character. I used the following jQuery to figure out IE was flagging this as invalid XML.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false,
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Then I escaped my hyphens with the ascii code

```
&#45;
```

Now, all is well.